# How to set the button action in tabelview for applewatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, xcode7, apple-watch

I'm working on demo in apple watch. In my demo app i'm displaying two buttons in tableview. Those buttons are displaying fine. Now i would like to add actions for the buttons. I don't understand how to give the button actions for the button.

Please can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to add `WKInterfaceButton` action programmatically as you need to connect the action in interface builder.

As you can not create the `WKInterfaceButton` programmatically so you can not set selector (action) programmatically too.

[Read Document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacebutton)

Comment: Do you have any idea about how the button actions working in instagram app in apple watch. because i'm using something like that.

Comment: @narendrakumarb i dont use it but may be it's not table row or different Control.